# Creating a self-contained python executable in Linux

Tags: linux, python-3.x

I have written a python app that depends on several packages and I would like to create a self-contained executable file.

I understand that all Linux distos come with Python pre-installed, but since some of the end users might not have internet access it would be highly desirable if I could pack everything on a DVD or USB and just ship it to them.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into http://www.pyinstaller.org/ ? I use py2exe (a similar windows version) and have had success with it.

Comment: I did try to use pyinstaller, but one of the packages I am using heavily depends on c++shared libraries. Pyinstaller seems to only work well with pure pyhton apps, but maybe I am wrong. Pyinstaller, seems to work packaging everyhting together, but whenI try to run the app it complains abount not being able to find the shared C++ libraries.